# Max Flow on low depth DAGs

Tags: efficiency, network-flow, dag

I have a family of acyclic networks in which every path from the source of a given network to its target has length exactly $3$. I'm aware of [a publication](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=34251) that in general, finding a max flow in a DAG is no simpler than finding one in a cyclic network, but unfortunately the only places I could find it put a paywall there. In addition to all my networks being DAGs, their depth is limited as well and I'm hoping this might make finding a max flow easier.

Is there a known approach to find a max flow in a DAG where each path from source to target has length exactly $3$ that has lower complexity than the available max flow algorithms for general networks?

Comment: Maybe a bit more general: what if we consider DAGs with $s$-$t$-paths of at most some constant length $k$? The reason I bring this up is because many issues that can be modeled with flows are modeled with networks of the described structure.